# NGINX - using sub_filter to change a path in a proxy pass location block

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

So I have an NGNIX server that receives traffic from the same location (Akamai) and based on the path of the incoming URL I send the traffic to different applications.

I have added a new origin to Akamai and this now means that some incoming requests now have a new path. The problem is that my application needs the path to be a certain value.

As I am sharing the Akamai slot with other origins I can't send the request with the same path to two different origins as the slot gets confused as to which origin server to direct the traffic at.

So what I would like to do is change the path before passing it to the application.
I am not sure on the best way to do this and need some assistance.
Should I use rewrite, redirect or sub_filter?

I have actually tried all three but I am missing something in this very simple task.

```
location /incoming_path {
      max_ranges 0;
      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
      proxy_pass https://\$upstream_application:9002;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/conf.d/server_cert.pem;
      proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/server_key.pem;
      proxy_set_header Host               \$host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          \$proxy_protocol_addr;
      sub_filter_types *;
      sub_filter "https://\$proxy_host/incoming_path" "https://\$host/new_path"
      sub_filter_once on;
    }
```

Really would appreciate any ideas/thoughts on how to achieve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to have worked:

```
location /incoming_path {
      max_ranges 0;
      rewrite /incoming_path/(.*) /new_path/$1  break;
      proxy_pass https://\$upstream_application:9002;
      proxy_ssl_server_name on;
      proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/conf.d/server_cert.pem;
      proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/server_key.pem;
      proxy_set_header Host               \$host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          \$proxy_protocol_addr;
    }
```

Comment: You don't even need to rewrite an URI, simply use `proxy_pass https://$upstream_application:9002/new_path;`. Why are you prepending all the variable names with a slash? It should break your config, I don't understand how it can keep working using them.

Comment: They are required as the config file is generated in a heredoc inside a docker entrypoint script.

Comment: I did try setting the proxy_pass as suggested above but it didn't work - I didn't investigate further and switched back to rewrite.